# Can anyone recommend a beginner DBA course in London

Tags: sql-server-2012

My organisation is in need of a SQL Server DBA and as the companies only "SQL Guy" my boss has suggested me to take SQL Server DBA course.  My general T-SQL knowledge is fairly good, I can write fairly complicated queries, have done stuff with stored procedures etc.  But when it comes to proper DBA knowledge, is where I fall down.  All my previous role had a DBA team who guarded their knowledge jealously so I am missing lots of best practice knowledge on how to deal with SQL server.

Can anyone recommend a good beginner SQL Server 2012 DBA course in London (UK)?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Its totally offtopic ..

Comment: I agree its offtopic I am not aware about any such course in London. Ther are many independant consultants here which provide online course you might get lucky.

Comment: Why dont you go for Microsoft certifications? https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-462.aspx or choose 461 for querying sql server,462 is more admin stuff.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [career advice](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Ask your boss to get you a pluralsight subscription.

Additionally, read answers from people like Paul White, Aaron Bertrand, Remus, etc and try to answer questions on this site.

Read blogs from sqlskills.com, brentozar.com, mssqltips.com, sqlperformance.com.

Also folks from sqlskills and brentozar are giving inperson training in LD.

Sqlbits event in UK and the videos on it are extremely helpful and don't forget virtual academy from Microsoft.